# How do I make a button highlighted with a description in an android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android app and I want to highlight a button on the first use. I have seen exactly what I want in other apps, such as the BBC iPlayer app. As shown in the image, there is a wide black circle around the cast button with a description of what is is.

[screenshot from phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfl4h.jpg)

How can I implement something similar in my own app?

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: Please show us your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)  will do the trick, here is how you use it :

In your grade :

```
implement 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
```

And in your code :

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
.setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
.setContentTitle("title text")
.setContentText("some text")
.hideOnTouchOutside()
.build();
```